# PDO: Using variable to SELECT specific fields

Tags: php, pdo

I currently have the below construct to create a Member object:

```
class Member{   
private $member_id = 0;
private $name, $surname, $email;

public function __construct(){} 
    
public function construct($conn, $param_select = '*', $param_member_id){
    $query_rs_this = $conn->prepare('SELECT :select FROM members WHERE 
                                            member_id = :member_id
                                        ORDER BY members.surname');
                                        
    $query_rs_this->execute(array(':select' => $param_select, ':member_id' => $param_member_id));
    $rs_this = $query_rs_this->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query_rs_this->closeCursor();
    
    foreach($rs_this as $key => $value){
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
    unset($key);
}
```

I would like to pass a string containing the columns (field names) which should be selected from the database. Currently I am using this:

```
$temp = new Member();
$select = "name, surname, email";
$temp->construct($db_conn, $select, 1);
```

Where $select is the string containing the fields names.

As it stands, I get the following output:

> member_id: 0
>
> name:
>
> surname:
>
> email:
>
> ?: name, surname, email

This is supposed to be:

> member_id: 1
>
> name: John
>
> surname: Doe
>
> email: test@email.com

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: For one thing, you can't bind tables `SELECT :select` <= that's a no-no as is `execute(array(':select' => $param_select,`. Either select a table or set a variable for it; that is allowed.

Comment: Add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened and you will be alerted of errors.

Comment: I see... so I need to manually check and compile a list of columns to pull from my DB?

Comment: Yep / yep and yep ;-)

Comment: Hmpf. Thank you for the instant replies! I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, in trying to do so, PDO doesn't know how to look ahead as to which table to select. But you can set a variable for it. I.e.: `$table = "tablename";` then do `SELECT * FROM $table`

Comment: But they're right there! ... kidding. I'm going to get cracking on that switch statement and post back here as a possible solution.

What's the process for marking a question as solved? This is my first time posting :/

Comment: If you feel that the answer given below works for you, then just accept that one. I hardly put in answers anymore. Comments can be just as good and effective ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish essentially the same thing, you could have a whitelist of fields to select, then build the string of fields yourself.

```
public function construct($conn, 
                          $param_select = array('name', 'surname', 'email'),
                          $param_member_id) 
{
    $available_fields = array('name', 'surname', 'email');
    $select_fields_array = array_intersect($param_select, $available_fields);
    $select_fields = implode(", ", $select_fields_array);
    $query_rs_this = $conn->prepare("SELECT $select_fields FROM members WHERE 
                                        member_id = :member_id
                                    ORDER BY members.surname");

    $query_rs_this->execute(array(':member_id' => $param_member_id));
    $rs_this = $query_rs_this->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query_rs_this->closeCursor();

    foreach($rs_this as $key => $value){
        $this->$key = $value;
    }
    unset($key);
}
```

OR

```
public function construct($conn, 
                          $param_select = array('name', 'surname', 'email'),
                          $param_member_id) 
{

    $query_rs_this = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE 
                                        member_id = :member_id
                                    ORDER BY members.surname");

    $query_rs_this->execute(array(':member_id' => $param_member_id));
    $rs_this = $query_rs_this->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query_rs_this->closeCursor();

    foreach($rs_this as $item){
        foreach($param_select as $field) {
             $this->$field = $item[$field];
        }
    }
    unset($key);
}
```

Comment: Now there's an idea! Excellent. 

However, when I'm reading in several hundred rows, with lots of columns, isn't that going to cause unecessary memory usage (and therefor time delay)?

Comment: Possible - just modified it to a safe way of building the fields to select yourself.  A little more annoying as if you add a field you'll have to change the code to allow it, but performance-wise should be faster

Comment: That, my dear Sir, is perfect. Hard-coding the available fields is fine by me.

Thank you.